# how to use replace function with item().name in dynamic content in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to replace a file name from foreach activity in ADF using item().name and replace function..
I'm trying to replace '-' with '_' in the file name and my content for dynamic content is
`.create table @replace(@item().name,'-','_')` (name:string,timestamp:date,avg_value:string).
But I'm getting the error saying this is not right syntax.

Can anyone help here?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have used is incorrect. I tried using the same syntax as yours to create a table, where I get the table name from `get metadata` activity. The following is the query (to create table in SQL database for *demonstration*), with dynamic content, that I used.

```
create table @replace(@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,'.','_') (name varchar(20))
```

[image]

- I corrected the syntax and used the following query to get the correct output:

```
create table @{replace(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,'.','_')} (name varchar(20))
```

- This will help to overcome the error. You can change your dynamic content to the following:

```
.create table @{replace(item().name,'-','_')} (name:string,timestamp:date,avg_value:string)
```

- The error occurs because, when we want to use expressions inside strings (in this case it is a query), we need to enclose the expression inside `@{...}`. This is called **`String Interpolation`** and you can refer to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-expression-language-functions#:%7E:text=a%20feature%20called-,string%20interpolation,-where%20expressions%20are) to understand more about it.